# Proverb - If someone inadvertently makes their life worse

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request, proverbs

Let’s say someone takes a wrong decision instead of thinking clearly, which leads him to another wrong decision and on and on. I heard that there is a proverb - "give him enough rope to hang himself". This is done by someone else, whereas in my example the subject is the person themselves.

What is the best way or proverb to describe this person?

Comment: These expressions might be useful: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downward%20spiral (see the example sentence), https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shoot_oneself_in_the_foot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idiom is [**to be your own worst enemy**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-your-own-worst-enemy):

> [Cambridge]
>
> to cause most of your problems or most of the bad things that happen to you yourself, because of your character:
>
> *Carrie is her own worst enemy - she's always arguing with people.*

It's often used when there's a pattern of behaviour and somebody ends up getting into a bad situation *again*.

Comment: I've always been curious about the exact meaning of the somewhat opaque set phrase [***a fool unto himself**,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+fool+unto+himself%22) and when I read this answer it set me thinking *a person who makes foolish choices, to his own detriment*. But in the first half-dozen of those 91 written instances, I see 1) *A fool is a fool unto himself until he opens his mouth, then he is a fool to everyone;* 2) *He's his own master now, so he can be, as they say, a law unto himself and a fool unto himself*,...

Comment: 3) ***a fool unto himself'**, meaning: no matter how illogical a deed may seem, you can count on it that there is a rationale behind it for the performer of the act.* I'm not really any the wiser. (Eek! Maybe ***I'm*** the fool! :)